# How to specify function search path for Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

I am linking to a FUNC_A from a doxygen documentation block by typing "#FUNC_A", and it gave me an error of:

explicit link request to 'FUNC_A' could not be resolved.

FUNC_A is defined in a different directory than the current file. How to I ask doxygen to search specifically that directory for symbol "FUNC_A"?

Comment: Have you doxygenized `FUNC_A` and the file that contains it?

Comment: @downhillFromHere I have not, and that is indeed the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` signifies an HTML link, which is probably not what you want.

You can document any function in an arbitrary file using `\fn`. This might work in a file with a `\file` directive:

```
/**
 *  \fn     FUNC_A
 *  \brief  This function does nothing.
 *  \param  This parameter is unused.
 *  \return Always returns 42.
 */
```

Comment: I am trying include a link to a function in my description. I am trying to document FUNC_B and say something link "FUNC_B is a wrapper around #FUNC_A"

Comment: I found the problem. FUNC_A() does not have documentation :p so there is no html page to link to.